# Ignore numbers in a text file when scanning it in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I am doing an assignment in Java that requires us to read two different files. One has the top 1000 boy names, and the other contains the top 1000 girl names. We have to write a program that returns all of the names that are in both files. We have to read each boy and girl name as a String, ignoring the number of namings, and add it to a HashSet. When adding to a HashSet, the add method will return false if the name to be added already exists int he HashSet. So to find the common names, you just have to keep track of which names returned false when adding. My problem is that I can't figure out how to ignore the number of namings in each file. My HashSet contains both, and I just want the names.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Names {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> boynames = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> girlnames = new HashSet<String>();
    boynames = loadBoynames();

    System.out.println(girlnames);

}

private static Set<String> loadBoynames() {
    HashSet<String> d = new HashSet<String>();
    File names = new File("boynames.txt");
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(names);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find boy names file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while(s.hasNext()){

        String currentName = s.next();
        d.add(currentName.toUpperCase());

    }
    return d;
    }
}
```

My plan is to take the HashSet that I currently have and add the girl names to it, but before I do I need to not have the numbers in my HashSet.

I tried to skip numbers with this code, but it just spat out errors

```
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    if (s.hasNextInt()){     
        number = s.nextInt();
    }else{
        String currentName = s.next();
        d.add(currentName.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there an exact pattern? Like "name - number"? If so, you could just split the file. `String line = s.next().split(" - ")[0]`. Same goes for spaces and commas. Just show couple of rows of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use regex to replace all numbers (or more special chars if needed)

`testStr = testStr.replaceAll("\\d","");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use StreamTokenizer (java.io) class to read file. it will split your file into tokens and also provide type of token like String value, number value in double data type, end of file, end of line). so you can easily identify the String token.
You can find details from here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Comment: This is defiantly something that good to know. I will investigate farther.Thanks for the help.